# What is a good way to decorate an iterator to alter the value before next is called in python?

Tags: python, validation, iterator, generator, decorator

I am working on a problem that involves validating a format from within unified diff patch.

The variables within the inner format can span multiple lines at a time, so I wrote a generator that pulls each line and yields the variable when it is complete.

To avoid having to rewrite this function when reading from a unified diff file, I created a generator to strip the unified diff characters from the line before passing it to the inner format validator. However, I am getting stuck in an infinite loop (both in the code and in my head). I have abstracted to problem to the following code. I'm sure there is a better way to do this. I just don't know what it is.

```
from collections import Iterable

def inner_format_validator(inner_item):
    # Do some validation to inner items
    return inner_item[0] != '+'

def inner_gen(iterable):
    for inner_item in iterable:
        # Operates only on inner_info type data
        yield inner_format_validator(inner_item)

def outer_gen(iterable):
    class DecoratedGenerator(Iterable):
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def next(self):
            # Using iterable from closure
            for outer_item in iterable:
                self.outer_info = outer_item[0]
                inner_item = outer_item[1:]
                return inner_item
    decorated_gen = DecoratedGenerator()
    for inner_item in inner_gen(decorated_gen):
        yield inner_item, decorated_gen.outer_info

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    def wrap(string):
        # The point here is that I don't know what the first character will be
        pseudo_rand = len(string)
        if pseudo_rand * pseudo_rand % 2 == 0:
            return '+' + string
        else:
            return '-' + string

    inner_items = ["whatever"] * 3
    # wrap screws up inner_format_validator
    outer_items = [wrap("whatever")] * 3
    # I need to be able to
    # iterate over inner_items
    for inner_info in inner_gen(inner_items):
        print(inner_info)
    # and iterate over outer_items
    for outer_info, inner_info in outer_gen(outer_items):
        # This is an infinite loop
        print(outer_info)
        print(inner_info)
```

Any ideas as to a better, more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something simpler, like this:

```
def outer_gen(iterable):

    iterable = iter(iterable)
    first_item = next(iterable)
    info = first_item[0]

    yield info, first_item[1:]

    for item in iterable:
        yield info, item
```

This will execute the 4 first lines only once, then enter the loop and yield what you want.

You probably want to add some `try`/`except` to cacth `IndexErrors` here and there.

If you want to take values while they start with something or the contrary, remember you can use a lot of stuff from the `itertools` toolbox, and in particular `dropwhile`,  `takewhile` and `chain`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['+foo', '-bar', '+foo']
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.startswith('+'), l))
['+foo']
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('+'), l))
['-bar', '+foo']
>>> a = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.startswith('+'), l)
>>> b = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('+'), l)
>>> list(itertools.chain(a, b))
['+foo', '-bar', '+foo']
```

And remember that you can create generators like comprehension lists, store them in variables and chain them, just like you would pipe linux commands:

```
import random

def create_item():
    return random.choice(('+', '-')) + random.choice(('foo', 'bar'))

random_items = (create_item() for s in xrange(10))
added_items = ((i[0], i[1:]) for i in random_items if i.startswith('+'))
valid_items = ((prefix, line) for prefix, line in added_items if 'foo' in line)

print list(valid_items)
```

With all this, you should be able to find some pythonic way to solve your problem :-)

Comment: I think the last example is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't like this very much, but at least it's shorter and a tad more pythonic:

```
from itertools import imap, izip
from functools import partial

def inner_format_validator(inner_item):
    return not inner_item.startswith('+')

inner_gen = partial(imap, inner_format_validator)

def split(astr):
    return astr[0], astr[1:]

def outer_gen(iterable):
    outer_stuff, inner_stuff = izip(*imap(split, iterable))
    return izip(inner_gen(inner_stuff), outer_stuff)
```

[EDIT] `inner_gen()` and `outer_gen()` without imap and partial:

```
def inner_gen(iterable):
    for each in iterable:
        yield inner_format_validator(each)

def outer_gen(iterable):
    outer_stuff, inner_stuff = izip(*(split(each) for each in iterable))
    return izip(inner_gen(inner_stuff), outer_stuff)
```

Maybe this is a better, though different, solution:

```
def transmogrify(iter_of_iters, *transmogrifiers):
    for iters in iter_of_iters:
        yield (
            trans(each) if trans else each
                for trans, each in izip(transmogrifiers, iters)
        )

for outer, inner in transmogrify(imap(split, stuff), inner_format_validator, None):
    print inner, outer
```

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to use `functools.partial`. The tools are pretty nifty, but I find this solution a bit hard to follow. Would there be any performance benefits to doing it this way?

Comment: One problem is the argument unpacking in `izip(*imap(split, iterable))` which unpacks the whole splitted iterable into memory at once. See my other solution for an alternative that avoids this. I think it's quite pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will do what you intended if you change the definition of DecoratedGenerator to this:

```
class DecoratedGenerator(Iterable):
    def __iter__(self):
        # Using iterable from closure
        for outer_item in iterable:
            self.outer_info = outer_item[0]
            inner_item = outer_item[1:]
            yield inner_item
```

Your original version never terminated because its `next()` method was stateless and would return the same value every time it was called.  You didn't need to have a next() method at all, though--you can implement `__iter__()` yourself (as I did), and then it all works fine.